# My Association Bonus not reflected in my Stack Overflow Account

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

I have joined Android Enthusiasts and Super User and I got 100 as a association bonus because I have 327 reputation in stack overflow. But that 100 reputation not reflected in the my stack overflow account. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Association Bonus is awarded a maximum of one time per site. And you are already awarded the association bonus for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553563/androidlearner?tab=reputation).

Have a look at [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/187824)

Comment: Does it mean that if I join other sites say Mathematics and then i get 100 as a association bonus but that not reflected every time in my stack overflow reputation as i have already got that?

Comment: @AndroidLearner - Absolutely you will not be awarded bonus **second** time for Stack Overflow or any other sites. Have a look at [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/187824)

Comment: Thanks buddy..confusion clear... :)